# can't start notepad on remote machine using psexec

Tags: windows, psexec

I need execute some script in remote computer, I try to start notepad. I use psexec, this command

```
psexec -e -i 1 \\localhost -u domain\user -p password cmd /c notepad.exe
```

successfully opens notepad on my local machine, but doesn't do it on remote.
I can't see any error, output is the same as I see after executing on local machine:

```
PsExec v2.0 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
```

What could be a reason I can't execute notepad successfully on remote machine?

Comment: Did you check with Task Manager (or similar) whether notepad.exe is running but invisible?

Comment: yes, I have checked, it is not

Answer (score 5):

To start notepad on remote machine using psexec:

```
psexec \\RemoteserverHOSTNAMEorIPADDRESS -u domain\user -p password -d -i cmd /c notepad.exe
```

For more information.....[PsExec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html)

Comment: Perhaps a little more emphasis on the `-i` for **interactive** option?  BTW that help page says to NOT use `-d` for interactive applications.