# How to make PSexec launch bat file on currently logged in user account

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I am currently trying to figure out if PSexec has the ability to launch a batch file on the currently logged on user's account.  I'm attempting to open a wep page with a batch file on multiple computers on a domain.  I would like to know if it is possible to launch the file with the logged on users account so they see the opened weppage.  Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't start notepad on remote machine using psexec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843526/cant-start-notepad-on-remote-machine-using-psexec)

Answer (score 3):

Interactive mode?

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec#using-psexec):

**PsExec -i**

> Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the
> specified session on the remote system. If no session is specified the
> process runs in the console session.

`PsExec.exe -s -i 1 \\computername notepad.exe`

Comment: In fairness it's often hard to know what to look for.  In this instance, you might not know "interactive" is the keyword you need.

Comment: I apologize.  I had been using google for quite a while before I decided to ask here. I had read about interactive mode but was not sure if that was what I was looking for or not for I am new to using programs such as psexec.  I'm sorry for wasting your time but truly appreciate the quick response.